# Eloquent JavaScript looping a triangle exercise solution question

Tags: javascript, html, eloquent

I had to check the solution for the first exercise in the book, and as I understand it, it's almost identical to my answer.

The exercise:

Write a loop that makes seven calls to console.log to output the following triangle:

the solution, that is given by the book:

```
    for (let line = "#"; line.length < 8; line += "#")
    console.log(line);
```

and my solution:

```
    for (let hash = '#'; hash.length <= 7; hash++) { 
    console.log(hash);
    };
```

My question is, why my loop doesn't loop? As it is explained in the book:

For counter += 1 and counter -= 1, there are even shorter equivalents: counter++ and counter--.

So by this logic, it should work.

Comment: `hash` is `#`. You can't increment `#`. The first example simply concatenates a new `#` on to the existing `hash` string.

Comment: `++` operator is used to  increment numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to increment a character. This doesn't concatenate to the character as you want it to and instead increases the ASCII value of the character.

Modify your code a bit:

```js
for (let hash = "#"; hash.length <= 7; hash += "#") {
    console.log(hash);
};
```

`hash` should be a string so that you can concatenate to it; furthermore, you shouldn't try to increment `hash` but rather concatenate to it on every iteration of the loop.